# How can I do this shadow on React Native

Tags: react-native

how can I do this shadow in react native? The only shadow that seems to work is with `elevation` but the shadow is added all around the box. I need it only on the bottom.

[shadow exapmple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3whx.png)

Comment: Why are you mentioning React Native, if you want to build a shadow you need some css, do you face any issue adding css in react native ?

Comment: I added css but it's seems that only elevation prop is doing something and I'm not able to set the shadow on the bottom how it's in the picture.

Comment: Could you post your component with the code or even a runnable example with a code snippet : https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link :

[React Native Shadow Creator](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/)

Comment: Thanks. Used it but the result is not the one I'm looking for. Only the elevation prop seems to have some effect, but I can't set the shadow only on the bottom like on the picture.

Comment: To achieve that you must use multiple Views and some overflow:'hidden' on some of them.